# No matching function for call to cl::Program::build()

Tags: c++, opencl

I have made a class for the devices, context and command queue of OpenCL device. But during my calling it and using it, is giving me the issues.

Here is My class in oclenvironment.h:

```
class oclenvironment
{
 public:
 oclenvironment();
 oclenvironment(int& status, int dev_type);
 ~oclenvironment();

 const cl::Device* GetDevice();
 const cl::Context *GetContext();
 const cl::CommandQueue* GetQueue();

private:

 std::vector<cl::Platform> _platform;
 std::vector<cl::Device> _devices;
 cl::Context             _context;
 cl::CommandQueue        _queue;
};
```

My cpp file, declaration of the functions:

```
clenvironment::oclenvironment(int& status,int dev_type)
{
   status = cl::Platform::get(&_platform);
   if(!_platform.empty())
   {
    auto err = _platform[0].getDevices(dev_type,&_devices);
    if(err!=0){
        status = err;
        return;
    }
    _context = new cl::Context(&_devices,NULL,0,0,&err);
    if(err!=0){
        status = err;
        return;
    }
    _queue = new  cl::CommandQueue(*_context,_devices[0],CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE,&err);
    if(err!=0){
        status = err;
        return;
    }
  }
}



const cl::Device *oclenvironment::GetDevice()
{
   return &_devices[0];
}

const cl::Context *oclenvironment::GetContext()
{
return _context;}

const cl::CommandQueue *oclenvironment::GetQueue()
{
  return _queue;
}
```

Now in my main.cpp:

```
 int err = 0;
 oclenvironment env(err,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU);

   auto devices = env.GetDevice();
   auto ctx = env.GetContext();
   auto queue = env.GetQueue();

    cl::Program::Sources source(1,std::make_pair(code.c_str(),strlen(code.c_str())));
    cl::Program prg(*ctx,source);
    err = prg.build(*devices,nullptr,0,0);  // I am getting error here
```

During build, I am getting error as **"no matching function for call to cl::Program::build(const cl::Device&, std::nullptr_t,int,int)"**

It must be some silly mistake during calling or declaring or defining.

Comment: Build function expects vector of devices, so: `const std::vector<cl::Device> d(1, *devices); err = prg.build(d, nullptr, 0, 0);`. Besides your code is terrible. There are a lot more issues, like assigning newly allocated memory to a variable instead of pointer, etc. Next time please have better code, otherwise you are getting less chances that somebody is willing to have a look at your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have solved it though. I was going to use shared pointer instead of new, and I will too. But I don't think any thing else is that terrible. If there is anything else I can improve except _new_, please let me know.

Comment: No, I just meant the mistakes were terrible which have to fixed first until you get to the line with the problem you were facing.

Comment: Let me understand. You are using the C++ CL API, to get advantage of easier error handling, and automatic memory deallocation. But then, you use new and pointers all over the place. So what is the point then? Use the C API. BTW your example is leaking memory at any error, and even in normal operation.